# How to change dlink dir-524 router link port from 80 to 1088

Tags: router, port

How to change dlink dir-524  router link(192.168.0.1) port from 80 to 1088

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be such an option. You can set the port to 1080 in Tools->Admin, but that seems to only apply to remote-management, that is, from the the web, not local. (I tried changing it and it had no effect locally.)